# MySQL Kafka ELK Stack Date Issue

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, apache-kafka-connect

I am creating Data Ingestion from:

`MySQL --> Kafka --> Logstash --> Elasticsearch --> Kibana`

I am able to pipeline data from MySQL till Kibana, but I am facing issues while dealing with "Date" column in the MySQL table.

The Date column is appearing as EPOCH date in Kafka topic, and in ES document.

Can we convert it to date format "yyyy-mm-dd" in Elasticsearch/Logstash part?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: use an Elasticsearch dynamic template to define the date field as `date` and Elasticsearch will then interpret the epoch value correctly.

Do you know that you don't need Logstash in there at all? You can just use the Elasticsearch sink for Kafka Connect. You can get this [separately](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch), or as part of [Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/).

You'll want to follow this blog series I'm writing here, which builds out exactly this pipeline (MySQL -> Kafka -> Elasticsearch) : https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/